# How to export multiple data files conditionally in Stata

Tags: export, stata

I read multiple dta files in a folder and export them in the csv format. I should export dta files the sample size of which is greater than 30.

```
cd D:\myfolder\
/* There are many dta files in myfolder */
fs *.dta
foreach f in `r(files)' {
    use `f', clear
    export delimited using "D:\csvfolder\mycsvfile_`f'.csv", novarnames replace
}
```

How can I prevent exporting data sets that contain 30 observations or less?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `if`:

```
clear

set obs 29
gen t = "should not be here"

tempfile file1
save "`file1'"

clear

set obs 31
gen t = "should be here"

tempfile file2
save "`file2'"

clear

*-----

foreach f in file1 file2 {
    use "``f''", clear
    if _N > 30 {
        export excel using "~/Desktop/mycsvfile_`f'.xls"
    }
}
```

See http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/multiple-operations/ for different concepts of `if` used in Stata.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`if c(N)>30 export delimited using ...`